# 404 error in new page created in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've created one `test.php` file in location `applications\views\test\test.php` with controller in `application\controller\Test.php` & model in `applications\models\Test_model.php`.

In my `routes.php` file, I have added `$route['test']='test/view'`.

Please note there are some files present already which are working quite fine, one of which is `login.php` & it has value in `routes.php` as `$route['login']='login/view'`. Plus this file does have same model & controller files in likewise location.

When I try to access `localhost\test`, it gives me 404 error whereas for `localhost\login` works quite fine.

Can anybody help in routing? I'm new to codeigniter & I could not resolve this issue.

**EDIT**

htaccess works fine as `localhost\login` is loading properly along with other few files.

**EDIT 2**

**Test_model.php**

```
<?php
class Test_model extends CI_Model{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->load->database();
  }
}
?>
```

**test.php**

```
<div>Testing</div>
```

**Test.php**

```
<?php
class Test extends MY_Controller{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('test_model');
  }
  public function view()
  {
    $this->loadHeader();
    $this->load->view('test/test');
    $this->loadFooter();
  }
}
?>
```

**routes.php**

```
$route['test'] = 'test/view';
```

**EDIT 3**

When I try to access `localhost\application\controllers\Test.php`, it gives me an error that says `Class My_Controller` not found. However, when I attempt to do it with any other file let's `login` with with the same location, it gives me the same error.

So I guess, it's able to find the controller because it's giving an error obviously but not able to load anything else.

Is there some sort of config file in which I have to mention every new page I create or something? There has to be something. This is pretty basic & I'm not able to get to the root of it.

**EDIT 4**

So this is what a problem is. When I copied my test view file to pages folder, it worked. Of course in controller I edited path of the file.

Now the real question is why didn't new folder named test under views work?

Comment: Your route.php is linking to a ``view`` method which does not exists. And I think since your controller name is similar to your route & you're using index method then it should work without that $route thing you have.

Comment: Yeah but same goes for login file, too. It has, login/view & it works fine with same exact parameters. And without $route, it doesn't work, not even login file.

Comment: Your test controller does not have a view method there's no test/view defined in the code you posted

Comment: Okay, let's edit `index` to `view` in controller. This isn't working also.

Comment: In your view function within the controller, see if you can get it to first load the welcome page view.  Load nothing but that, and see if the page comes up.  If so, then you might have a problem in one of the loads you are currently doing (header, view or footer).

Comment: Also, question:  you say that the login route is working, but does your view function within your login controller have a parameter being passed in like the one above ($page = 'test')?  If not, that could also be the problem.  Your route isn't setup to expect a parameter.

Comment: I tried removing parameter & directly load test file. 404 error only.

Comment: @ShanilSoni Have you tried (`localhost/test`) by removing this line `$route['test'] = 'test/view';` from routes.php?

Comment: I find it would be better to also autoload the database library other wise your going to have to enter `$this->load->database();` in every time

Comment: To access controller try `http://localhost/yourproject/test` make sure your base url is set `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';`

Comment: @RejoanulAlam I tried that but it's giving me 404 error only.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Yeah. that's what I'm doing but it's not working.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Can you look at my edit 4 & try to explain that behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.htaccess` file and paste this code below

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Sorry didn't mention earlier, htaccess works fine. RewriteRule is already present. Also, as I mentioned `localhost\login` is working properly along with other few files which are there.

Comment: Make sure the class name has the same name as the file name for both controllers and the models. Eg controller `Test.php` should have a class name of `class Test extends CI_Controller`.

Comment: Yes, it's there, too. Same class names as file names.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the culprit was this line in `routes.php` file:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

I was adding other route below this so it was getting default behaviour. I put them above this line & it worked like a charm. I never thought this could be the issue.

Line number matters, now.